# C++ for loops "Statement has no effect" warning?

Tags: c++, for-loop

so I just started learning programming with C++ and I'm currently messing with basic console programs. I wanted to make a little spam program. here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string a;
int b;

void repetition(){
    cout << "Please enter the number of time you want the text to be spammed" << endl;
    cin >> b;
}

void text(){
    cout << "Please enter the text you want to spam." << endl;
    cin >> a;

    for(;b == 0;){
        cout << a << endl;
        b - 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to your auto-spammer!!" << endl;
    repetition();
    text();

    return 0;

}
```

I'm getting a warning saying "statement has no effect" for my for statement at line 20. I wanted to know why and how I could fix this. Thank you.

Comment: `b - 1;` has no effect: maybe `b -= 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `text()`, `b-1` indeed does nothing, you probably meant `--b`.  The first returns an rvalue which is then discarded, while the second decrements `b` by one and results in `b` (though you should look up the difference between `--b` and `b--` to understand how that statement actually works).  That said, the more colliquial way to do it is like this:

```
for(; b > 0; --b) //Also keep in mind that the second section of a for statement 
//is the continue condition, not exit
   cout << a << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop executes while the second statement is true. So unless you enter `0`, it will never execute.

The warning is for `b - 1;` . This reads the value of `b`, subtracts 1, and does nothing with the result. You probably meant `b = b - 1;`  (which can also be written as `b -= 1;`, or `--b;`).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is line 20:

```
b - 1;
```

That line by itself does nothing. The result of b-1 is never assigned to anything.

Try `--b`, which will decrement b by 1 and re-assign the result of that operation to b.

Comment: Unless you're relying on the value in an expression, prefer to use predecrement to postdecrement, i.e. `--b` rather than `b--`. For integers it shouldn't matter, but for more complex objects the predecrement avoids the construction of a temporary object.

Comment: That's a good point. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do print the text N number of times, so the proper loop to use is:

```
for (int i=0; i < b; i++)
   cout<<a<<endl;
```

Modifying b is generally not a good idea, you might need the value the user entered later on.